# Is there any recommended control for triple options like YES / NO / NONE?

Tags: gui-design, html, jquery

I'm designing a user opinion page where the user has three choices. For instance, if the question is "Is it suitable?" the three options could be "YES", "NO", or "NoIdea".

In this case, what control should I use?

If there aren't any native controls available, are there any angular-ui or jquery-ui plugins available for the control?

Comment: Think of it as a Likert scale with just three levels.

Comment: I want to use the btn-group above by AL.. but how can I get it to select Yes/ No, etc via Javascript?

Answer (score 30):

To select one option of a limited number of choices, [Radio Button Inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio) would be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, Radio Buttons are likely to be the best option here. Windows went through a phase of allowing "tri-state" Check Boxes (Yes/No/Indeterminate), but that was never a good UX.

Comment: @SteveJones Many installers use those, the third state indicating at a parent level that some but not all child elements are selected. I quite like it.

Comment: @OllieFord, You may like them, I understand them, but try explaining them to a normal user!   Try also watching someone that has never come across them before.

Comment: @OllieFord Yes, I get it, but they are not a good UX, especially for a casual user who may not have seen them before. IMHO, YMMV, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the other answers, radio buttons are the best choice for an input with 3 choices. According to GNOME developer, they are preferable for your problem because:

> Radio buttons are used in groups to select from a mutually exclusive set of options.

https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/radio-buttons.html.en

> Radio buttons or a list will often be preferable to a drop-down list, as they present all the available options at once without any further interaction.

https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/drop-down-lists.html.en

---

Unfortunately, the default style of radio buttons is boring, but the [`.btn-group` class](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-single) from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) can help you to improve the style of your radio buttons:

> [image: YES NO No Idea] (or) [image: YES NO No Idea]

JSFiddle demos :

- [no default value](http://jsfiddle.net/wyohwqec/)
- [*No Idea selected*](http://jsfiddle.net/wyohwqec/2/)
- [*No Idea selected* and colors](http://jsfiddle.net/wyohwqec/3/) (but it's hard to see which one is selected)

The downside is that it requires jQuery, Bootstrap CSS and JS (see the *External Resources* tab on these JSFiddle links for the CDN URLs).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label data-value="yes" class="control-label btn btn-default" for="button_1">
        <input id="button_1" name="opinion" required="required" value="yes" checked="checked" type="radio"/>
        YES
    </label>
    <label data-value="no" class="control-label btn btn-default" for="button_0">
        <input id="button_0" name="opinion" required="required" value="no" type="radio"/>
        NO
    </label>
    <label data-value="no_idea" class="control-label btn btn-default" for="button_void">
        <input id="button_0" name="opinion" required="required" value="no_idea" type="radio" />
        No Idea
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Worth noting that a commonly used name for those button groups is a segmented control. Helpful if you're Googling it!

Answer (score 6):

Generally, there are just two natural ways to set up a 1-out-of-many choice in HTML: a set of radio buttons, and a `select` element. The latter can be used with a `size` attribute specifying the number of options visible in the initial size, or with `size` defaulted to 1. For usabaility, it is best to have all options visible initially, so that the user can just select the right one, instead of first opening a menu. This is best done with radio buttons, because that’s the usual way and users are accustomed to it, instead of the listbox created by `<select size=3 ...>`. But sometimes you need to save space and must use a `select` element with `size` defaulted.

Normally you should *not* set any of the options as initially selected, since the case where the user does not answer at all could (and maybe should) be processed as differently from a “No idea” answer. Lack of any answer could be an oversight (the user missed the question).

Comment: Yes, having it initially un-selected is important, and this can be represented in a database as a Null value.

Answer (score 2):

I generally favor radio buttons but -- as an option to experiment and test with -- you can use a slider. EXAMPLE:

```
   YES
    _
    :
    :
    ▲
NO OPINION 
    ▼
    :
    :
    _
   NO
```

Be careful to factor in up/down and left/right prejudices/tendencies in your testing. Up tends to be "good" and down "bad". And left-right is inextricably intertwined in politics and political philosophy.

Comment: … who thinks of politics when using a slider?

Comment: @bjb568 That's the thing - You don't have to.  Many people won't be affected by this, but several users might be subconsciously swayed by their political preferences towards "the left" or "the right."

Comment: Therefore roads are dangerous as people may be swayed toward the wrong side… Wat? I guess if you were to think like that, down is bad since being low is like being a lower class which the mere existence of promotes racism. Red is bad because it's the color of blood. Yes is bad because it can lead to regret. 13 is bad…

Comment: @bjb568 - if the user perceives that your questionnaire has political overtones it may. The poster is talking about a user opinion page. You will be surprised what people perceive as political and may very well be influenced by it.

Comment: @bjb568 - No the roads aren't the same thing assuming everyone in an area (US) drive on the same side of the road. Now your mocking about this is interesting considering this is a UX site. Color and placement matter. And your example of down is a perfect one - if the questionnaire reflects "taste" (food, restaurants, fashion, home decor) it may overlap with social class in some people's minds and then up/down may very well enter into people's minds.

Comment: Oh, FSM… Isn't it more important that it doesn't look weird? People will be confused if they see a vertical slider since they aren't as common as horizontal sliders (which are built into HTML).

Comment: Is there actually *evidence* somewhere that people honestly link horizontal sliders with politics? Or is this just one of those "sounds plausible" suppositions that doesn't have a study behind it?

Comment: @ChrisHayes  I haven't seen any published articles with it in but in my user testing I have heard so many way out associations coming from test subjects mouths - from "seems gay, not interested) in reference to a series of colors to "seems too rah-rah patriotic, don't want that" to a background that was wavy and had reddish and whiteish stripes and in no way looked like a flag. I pointed it out only that people should take that into consideration. If you're querying people about their opinion on types of laptops I don't see how that would matter -- but perhaps it would in other things.

Comment: I’m skeptical that politics would bias our reaction to a left-right slider; but I *would* expect that our left-to-right reading could affect it significantly.  Moving to the right is strongly associated with progress towards completion; moving leftwards is associated with hesitation, back-tracking, hindrance.

Comment: I think you may be correct  re the left-right reading.It would be interesting see tests on native left-right readers (English, French) with right-left readers (Hebrew, Arabic).

Comment: The association between a horizontal slider with political stance is absolute bonkers. Talk about making a hen out of a feather, or a hen out of air rather... And I'd also add that a slider is a bad control for this type of input. A slider should be used in a scale, providing an interface to input eg. from **little** to **much** in the same unit. The OP asks for a control which allows for input that differentiates and excludes the options, yours is combining them. It's a bad idea. A -1 from me.

Comment: #ChrisHayes I wrote a letter to the Editor to a newspaper. Online, I saw my name as clickable in relation to the letter, I clicked through, and there was a horizontal scale with my mark in the middle between the ends of Left and Right.

Answer (score 1):

Using a select element makes the screen easier to read, especially when your page contains only a few Yes, rarely No, and most of None. The real problem I am trying to solve was selecting Yes with one click and keeping the advantage of the dropdown menu.

Here is my potential solution - the icon is added to rotate the selected value of the dropdown:

[image: Example]

Please let me know if you would like me to create a jQuery plugin from my code to try this idea.

Comment: Keyboard navigation with Tab is important. I was not able yet  to find a way to make my YNNA User Control navigate with Tab when no visible option has been selected (when it is still set to Null). Does yours allow keyboard navigation?

Comment: BreakingGnus,  the icon is not accessible by Tab (tabindex="-1").  The dropdown handles keyboard events on its own.

Answer (score 0):

As per your use case, radio button works best in this case. You can either place all the options in one line or one below the other. Hope this solves the problem.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftDlgJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net applications I created a "User Control" with a set of Radio Buttons for **Yes**, **No**, **NA** (not applicable) and **Null**. The Null entry is the default selection and is usually not visible. This control can be connected to a database column which allows Null and holds 'tiny' integer values of 1, 0, and -1 respectively.

I call this the YNNA control and it can be styled with CSS however you wish. I provided a way to drop off one of the options, and also a way to rename the options. It is very convenient. I have some forms with dozens of these. I also added a way to double-click one to reset the selection to Null (which is not visible) to un-choose if necessary. This takes a bit of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

An update to [@A.L](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/42017/a-l)'s answer

This is the Bootstrap 5 version of using input radio buttons in a button group.

[image: Bootstrap 5 button group]

[Bootstrap 5 Input Radios as buttons](https://codepen.io/nickolasjadams/pen/eYPyNgW?editors=1011)

jQuery is no longer a dependency. No CSS required. It's all built in with utility classes.

Filter Refunds
        
          
          No filter

```
      <input id="refund_only_refunds" name="refund_filter" class="btn-check" type="radio" value="only refunds">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="refund_only_refunds">Only Show Refunds</label>
      
      <input id="refund_only_nonrefunds" name="refund_filter" class="btn-check" type="radio" value="only non-refunds">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="refund_only_nonrefunds">Don't Show Refunds</label>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
  
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  
  <button type="button" id="get_value" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Get value</button>
  
  </form>
</div>
```